# How to make Oracle sqlplus command line utility non-interactive?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I am calling `sqlplus` from within a bash script, providing some arguments but there may potentially exist a situation where some of the arguments are not correct, for example the user name. In that case `sqlplus` reports an error that the user name or password is invalid and prompts the user to enter a user name. That prompt is not desired. I would want `sqlplus` to just report the error on stderr, bail out and exit with an error code. To perform completely non-interactively.

For example, the bash script calls out `sqlplus` like this:

```
sqlplus $username/$password@ORCLPDB1 @script.sql
```

If the `$username` variable is incorrect (like such user does not exist), it reports the error and keeps waiting for a new user name for the user to input to stdin. Does `sqlplus` have any feature to immediately quit on error, without prompting anything? If not, are there any simple and straightforward workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if sqlplus gets all of its commands piped to it into its standard input, it actually doesn't prompt the user for anything, no matter if the `-S` flag is provided or not. Also in this case the `@script.sql` parameter seems ignored (it doesn't get executed if given as a command line argument). So, to execute a script so that there are no prompts and errors make sqlplus actually exit with an error code, you have to call sqlplus like that:

```sh
sqlplus /nolog <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
connect $username/$password @ORCLPDB1
@script.sql
EOF
```

The `$?` variable is populated on error but the error code itself doesn't make much sense to me. It is not referring to the number in the `ORA-XXXXX` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There is an -s flag that stops any prompts for input.

Further details are here:

http://www.dbatoolz.com/t/sqlplus-s-shell-scripting.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. It just hides the prompt message but keeps expecting some input, therefore stalling.

Comment: So you used sqlplus -s $username/$password@ORCLPDB1 @script.sql?

Comment: Yes. [Stack Overflow wants messages to be longer so now it is longer]

Comment: How about with the Heredoc (<<EOF) as in the example?

Comment: Got it solved, thanks for the inspiration! Not sure if it is the best solution but seems to work for my case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the guide was indicating

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus -L $username/$password@ORCLPDB1 @script.sql should work.
-L option ensures that sqlplus doesn't prompt for invalid username and/or password and be able to exit from the shell.